# How can I get AngularJS binds working with a fancybox dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dialog, fancybox

I'm learning AngularJS and **I'm having some difficulties with dialogs**.

Since i'm converting my app from a classical Jquery-based to an angular one, i want to use Fancybox to open dialogs with custom dynamic HTML inside, with the fancybox open method.

```
$.fancybox.open(html);
```

**I wrote a service to use fancybox**: now i open my dialogs but **the content inside the dialog is not "compiled" against angular**, so any angular directive set on that HTML doesn't work.

**See the example**

http://plnkr.co/edit/UwryF1ocleyND7zxCGJz?p=preview

I imagine that the problem is in the service, but i don't know how to fix it. Could you show me how i can get an html sensible to angular directive inside the HTML shown in the dialog?

**UPDATE**:

i've tried to use `$compile`, and set a directive instead of a service (calling the method inside the directive directly from ng-click)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y18bRSMdV62VObMGJ2Ie?p=preview

what's wrong now? why my `$compile` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: you really need to wrap the whole fancyBox into an angular directive to make it work smoothly with angular

Comment: if `.wrapper` is unhidden, do the alerts work? I disable "display:none" and they didn't.

Comment: @JFK no they don't, because angular bindings are not compiled.

Comment: @charlietfl could you post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `angular` looks for function expressions *only* on the `scope` and NOT on `window` as plain-javascript does. Hence, when you add an `alert` function on the `$scope`, it will be wired correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/y02UMQ2kU4fh8Imsa82u?p=preview

```js
$scope.alert = function (phone) { window.alert(phone.name); };
```

Comment: future note for those using coffeescript:  Make sure that in your directive's function $scope.open_fancybox() that you end the line with return true. Otherwise, interacting with the DOM and Coffeescript's implicit return function can allow arbitrary injection.