# Why ngClick doesn't work anymore after $compile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

> http://plnkr.co/edit/kL2uLPQu2vHHKIvRuLPp?p=preview

After a click on the button, from the controller i call the service who compiles the html and inject it in the body.

The html is compiled (see "Hello World" from $scope.name) against the $scope of the controller, but ngClick doesn't work.

Why?

How i can compile against the scope of the single phone (inside the ng-repeat?)?

I know that it's better to have a directive in this case, but i need to understand how it works because i need it for a dialog (see [How can I get AngularJS binds working with a fancybox dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729384/how-can-i-get-angularjs-binds-working-with-a-fancybox-dialog))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two problems I see here both appear to stem from a misunderstanding of expressions and scope in angular.

When you use expressions in directives or bindings, such as in these two examples

```
<p>{{ phone.name }}</p>
<a ng-click="alert('angular')">Link</a>
```

they cannot access the JavaScript scope. Any identifiers used in these are coming from the angular scope, i.e. `$scope`. So

```
{{ phone.name }}
```

will display

```
$scope.phone.name
```

and

```
ng-click="alert('angular')"
```

will be trying to call

```
$scope.alert('angular')
```

Looking at your plunker, you are trying to use both `phone` and `alert` without assigning them to the scope. You can create a function to perform your alert by assigning it to your controller scope, but `phone` will be more difficult as it needs to be different every time.

You can either create a brand new scope for this and assign `phone` as I have done [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASM2nG?p=preview), or you can pass the scope from inside your `ng-repeat` and compile your new element in this scope as I have done [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tRR0K2?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

The name `alert` is not defined on the `$scope` with which the template is compiled. If you do include an `alert` function, then `ng-click` does work:

```js
$scope.alert = function (msg) { window.alert(msg); };
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/i6CoimlMuvPfu4iijbik?p=preview)

However, as you have yourself pointed out, this work is better suited for a `directive` than a service.